# flutter: change strings letters from the letters from list 1 to the letters from list 2

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to change a string letters from the letters from list 1 to the letters from list 2

and I couldn't find a way to do it

this is my 2 lists

```
 List En =  ["A","A","B","G","D","R","S","C","T","E","F","K","L","M","N","H","W","Y","Y"];
 List Ar =  ["ا","أ","ب","ج","د","ر","س","ص","ط","ع","ف","ق","ل","م","ن","ه","و","ى","ي"];
```

so if the string was "abc" for example it would get the equivalent of the chars A B C from list 1 and then translate them to the same indexes in list 2

Comment: There are two "A" in the `En` list. Can you give an example of the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why others are happy with linear searches of lists.  To me, that screams for setting up a map one time, and using it repeatedly.  Here's what I whipped up in DartPad:

```
void main() {
  var En = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  var Ar = ['1', '2', '3'];
  var en2ar = Map<String, String>.fromIterables(En, Ar);
  print(en2ar);
  var text = 'abcd';
  var output =
      text.replaceAllMapped(RegExp('.'), (Match m) => en2ar[m.group(0)] ?? '');
  print('$text => $output');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this function:

```
  setText(){
String input = 'ABC';
List text = input.split('');
String output = '';

List En =  ["A","A","B","G","D","R","S","C","T","E","F","K","L","M","N","H","W","Y","Y"];
List Ar =  ["ا","أ","ب","ج","د","ر","س","ص","ط","ع","ف","ق","ل","م","ن","ه","و","ى","ي"];

text.forEach((item){
  int index = En.indexWhere((element) => element == item);
  if(index != -1){
    output = output + Ar[index];
  }
});

return output;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

using the indexWhere method you can find the index of a certain char in array a then replace the char with the element at the same index in array b

I would use this flow

- cycle the characters of the string you want to repalce
- for every character you get the index of the array a
- add the item at the same index in the array b to a "result" string

You should now have a string "result" with the characters replaced